# Product of two natural numbers being greater than or equal to their sum minus one

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is the above inequality true?
If yes, could you please provide a proof.
If not, could you please tell in which cases it is true.

(Edit: This is related to McCormick Relaxation for binary variables and not natural numbers as I mistook it for. Relaxation for for $XY<=C$, in optimization problems.)

Comment: do you count zero as a natural number

Comment: $ab=(a-1+1)(b-1+1)=$ $(a-1)(b-1)+(a-1)+(b-1)+1=a+b-1+(a-1)(b-1)$.

Comment: No. Not counting zero. Answered my own question. Could you please comment on the McCormick Relaxation?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thats a+b-2 not a+b-1. Nope sorry I misread.

Comment: @TheNovice No, it is as I wrote.

Comment: Probably that is helpful for your question about McCormick Relaxation: https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/McCormick_envelopes

Comment: @user251257 : Yes, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the elementary question.

Let $X = 1$, $Y = 1$.

$XY = 1.  $
$X+Y-1 = 1$

Now we only need to notice that $XY$ increases at a faster pace than $X+Y-1.$
So this holds for all natural numbers.

Comment: This should probably be an edit to your original question (as it expands the question--a little more about what you know--but doesn't really answer the question).

Comment: I thought it did answer the question about $XY >= X+Y -1$

Comment: @user251257 : Sorry I do not mean to be rude, but is my logic wrong? If not why does it not answer the question which I asked? I am just failing to see how this does not answer the question.

Comment: As you increase X or Y, XY will increase more than X+Y

Comment: Increase X by 1, now X=2, XY =2, X+Y -1 =2. Increase Y by one, now XY = 4, X+Y -1 = 3. The difference between the two keeps on increasing. It's an observation. I am pretty sure the proof and it's theorem of it should be quite basic. Help me by providing it please?

Comment: @user251257 : Do you mean ask a new question about McCormick Relaxation?, because XY >= X+Y -1 is pretty clear to me now.

Comment: @user251257 : Thanks but I'll ask my professor this week. Also found a proof online. I will remove that from the answer.

Comment: In all fairness, while you've *convinced* yourself that it's true, this doesn't really seem to be an answer to the question; so I agree about that. On your assertion, consider the inductive step of moving from (WLOG) $X$ to $X + 1$. The difference of products will be $$(X+1)Y - XY = Y \ge 1 = (X + 1) + Y - (X + Y),$$ the right side being the difference of sums.

Comment: @pjs36 : Right, thanks for that, I did think it would be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

$ab - (a+b-1)
=ab-a-b+1
=(a-1)(b-1)
\ge 0
$
since $a \ge 1$
and $b \ge 1$.

There is equality
only when
at least one of the numbers
is equal to $1$.